# Error appeared after I add Google AdMob code

Tags: react-native, expo

I encounter an error message when I am trying to add a code for inserting Google AdMob advertisement into the app project. The code is:

```js
<AdMobBanner
  bannerSize="banner"
  adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3038938528713825/5887864345"
  testDeviceID="CF583E54-34C6-453C-80FC-493D2468A51E"
/>
```

snack.expo.io shown an error message and a [weblink](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=130&args%5B%5D=undefined&args%5B%5D=) to the error message after I added the code above. The error message is:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
> or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

I could not understand at all what causes this error to happen when I insert the code for Google AdMob into the project.

Here is the entire code of my project:

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import {AdMobBanner} from 'expo';

const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {

    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Home Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Page 2" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Page2')}
          />

          <AdMobBanner
            bannerSize="banner"
            adUnitID="ca-app-pub-3038938528713825/5887864345"
            testDeviceID="CF583E54-34C6-453C-80FC-493D2468A51E"
          />

      </View>
    );

}

const Page2Screen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Page 2 Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Page 3"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Page3')}
          />

      </View>
    );
}

const Page3Screen = ({ navigation }) => {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <Text>Page 3 Screen</Text>
          <Button
            title="Go to Home"
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Home')}
          />
          <Button
            title="Go back to first screen in stack"
            onPress={() => navigation.popToTop()}
          />
      </View>
    );
}

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
              <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Page2" component={Page2Screen} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Page3" component={Page3Screen} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Here the code of my package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native-screens": "~3.8.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "*",
    "@react-navigation/native": "*",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.10.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have expo listed as a dependency in your package.json, so your import will be undefined. Did you start the project with `expo init`?

You can try adding expo to your dependencies or initializing a new project with expo. I recommend starting a new project to get the benefit of any additional setup expo may do.